# Transformation & Mapping rule

Tags: functions, transformation

$y= 3f(-x+1)+2$

What is the mapping rule?

So I did:

$y= 3f(-x+1)+2 = 3f(-(x-1))+2$
$ \implies (x,y)\to (-x+1, 3y+2)$    (horizontal translation: 1 unit to the right)
$\implies (3,5)\to (-2,17)$

However the answer in the text book says the point is $(-4,17)$, which means the mapping rule must be $(-x-1)$, is the answer correct or mine?